# Do Dunwich monsters get removed from gate closings?

Tags: arkham-horror

When a gate is closed, do matching monsters in Dunwich get removed? I'm aware the monsters in Dunwich do not count toward the monster limit  as the vortices handle that dynamic. I would think the gate closing does affect all monsters across both boards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, monsters on the Dunwich board would also be removed.

From the [Arkham Horror Rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/AH_Rules_internat.pdf) (page 18):

> **Monsters and Closing Gates**
>
> When a gate is closed, all monsters in Arkham, the Sky,
> and the Outskirts that have the same dimension symbol
> (see “Monster Movement,” page 10) as the closed or
> sealed gate are removed from the board and returned to
> the cup.

and from the [Dunwich Horror Rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/DH_rules_english.pdf) (page 5):

> **The Phrase “in Arkham” on Cards**
>
> Cards that refer to “Arkham” also apply to locations and
> areas in Dunwich.

Thus all monsters on the Dunwich board are also considered to be "in Arkham", and would be removed.

Comment: Does this imply the sky and outskirts aren't "in Arkham"?

Comment: Absolutely. The phrase "in Arkham" specifically means all of the locations and street areas on the Arkham board. The Outskirts and the Sky are not "in Arkham".

Comment: @winterblood From the FAQ: "Q: If the number of monsters in Arkham is at the monster limit, and a monster that is on an expansion board moves
to the Sky, what happens to that monster? A: The monster is moved to the Outskirts. The Sky is considered part of Arkham, ..."

Comment: @Jefromi As far as I can tell, there is a distinct difference between the specific wording of "in Arkham" in the rules vs. the informal wording "part of Arkham" in the FAQ. But yes, there is a little ambiguity in the original rules regarding the sky, specifically in the section on Monster Limits and the Outskirts, but the vast majority of cases where both "in Arkham" and the Sky are mentioned, they are both mentioned specifically.

Comment: I feel that the fact Sky is mentioned separately when talking about closing gates, but then as Jefromi mentioned is also clearly stated as "part of Arkham". I don't know what to think about this, my best guess being to decide the Sky *is* part of Arkham and the mention in the gate closing text was simply an act of redundancy. The fact that monsters fly to and from it regularly does imply that making it part of Arkham makes sense, being overhead of the streets.